# How can I constrain the contents of a table cell which contains wide HTML to an overall particular width?

Tags: html, css

I have a table (not a set of divs) representing a "feed" of user posts. The table is in the middle of a page which is itself laid out in tables: a left one, the middle one with the feed, and the right one.

The problem is that sometimes people will add posts which are copy-pasted from an HTML source (e.g. MailChimp) and the source includes tables with their own widths, or wide divs, or large images, and the post is wider than the "feed width" on my page. When this happens, the feed stretches things out, pushing the cells on the right of the page further to the right.

I tried adding things like this around the table, or cells in the table:

```
<div style="max-width: 395px;">
```

That did have the effect of stopping the pushing and stretching of columns to the right of the middle feed, but for long posts the *content* of the middle feed itself now extends and appears *on top* of the items on the right it was previously pushing.

My question is is it possible to put a div around the middle feed table so (1) it is constrained to 395px width and (2) the content doesn't extend outside the table even if cells inside the table contain other tables, large images or text.

The text can word-wrap and the images can get cut-off if necessary.

If it isn't possible in tables, can I rewrite the whole thing using divs and make it work better than way?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please add your html so we can help you.

Comment: I wonder the best way of doing that. I grabbed the HTML for an offending table row, but it's long. It would be messy to directly add to my post. Should I put it up on Dropbox or somewhere and add a link? Thanks.

Comment: You can add that in snippet this will help you if not then use codepen or jsfiddle.

Comment: I would be interested to try a "fenced code block" but the snippet is 141 lines long, so I'm afraid it will just confuse the original post at this point. I'll check out codepen and jsfiddle (just for completeness sake). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with your explanation and without examples we don't help you so much, but i think i can help you.

with this CSS properties:

```
my-cell { 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    border: solid #5B6DCD 10px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

you can visit the MDN link: [box-sizing Mozilla developer's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

or you can try with this css property inside your div container or cell `overflow: hidden;`

hope this help you.

Comment: Your suggestion of adding `overflow: hidden;` to a surrounding div container seems to have worked perfectly for this problem. Notes: (1) Words don't wrap, they get cut off, as do images. But that's fine because there is a link to the full post there and a user who want to read it all can just click on it. (2) The style needed to be added to a div surrounding the table, and not to the table tag itself. Adding a style to the table tag had no effect. But when I surrounded the feed table with this div: `<div  style="width: 395 px; max-width: 395px; overflow: hidden;">` it had the desired effect.

Comment: Excellent! I'm glad. in future you can show to the user a modal that request a fragment of the post, and you can show only the fragment in yor table and avoid problems with overflow. (english provided by Google)

Comment: The person I was doing this for didn't like it. She said it looked weird. :( Is there a way to get the words to wrap so the words don't need to get cut off - just the images do? Thanks.

Comment: The only thing I can think of, without knowing more about how the site is built is to use iframe. check this fiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/yersskit/7p5wsemq/4/)